# Linq to Entities Group By DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities, grouping

I want to be able to get sales from the last 12 months, grouped by month. Here's what I have so far:

Class Definition:

```
        public DateTime DateSold { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }

        public int USDNumberItemsSold { get; set; }
        public int GBPNumberItemsSold { get; set; }
        public int EURNumberItemsSold { get; set; }
        public int TotalNumberItemsSold { get { return USDNumberItemsSold + GBPNumberItemsSold + EURNumberItemsSold; } }

        public decimal USDRevenueTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal GBPRevenueTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal EURRevenueTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal OverallEarnings { get { return USDRevenueTotal + GBPRevenueTotal + EURRevenueTotal; } }
```

My Linq query is as follows:

```
List<MonthlySales> monthlySales = (from sale in Sales
                                   orderby sale.DateSold descending
                                   group sale by sale.DateSold.Month into ds
                                   select new MonthlySales
                                   {
                                       DateSold = ds.Key,
                                       USDNumberItemsSold = ds.Where(it => it.USDCut.HasValue).Where(it => it.USDCut != 0).Count(),
                                       GBPNumberItemsSold = ds.Where(it => it.GBPrCut.HasValue).Where(it => it.GBPCut != 0).Count(),
                                       EURNumberItemsSold = ds.Where(it => it.EURCut.HasValue).Where(it => it.EURCut != 0).Count(),
                                       USDRevenueTotal = PerformCurrencyConversion(ds.Sum(it => it.USDCut.HasValue ? it.USDCut.Value : 0), 0M, 0M, reportRequest.BaseCurrency, endDate),
                                       GBPRevenueTotal = PerformCurrencyConversion(0M, ds.Sum(it => it.GBPCut.HasValue ? it.GBPCut.Value : 0), 0M, reportRequest.BaseCurrency, endDate),
                                       EURRevenueTotal = PerformCurrencyConversion(0M, 0M, ds.Sum(it => it.EURCut.HasValue ? it.EURCut.Value : 0), reportRequest.BaseCurrency, endDate),
                        }).Take(12).ToList();
```

I get the following error with this:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.DateTime'

because obviously DateTime.Now.Month is an int.

I tried using the following:

```
Month = ds.Key
```

Where 'Month' is an int. This was okay but for display purposes I don't have the year or things like that.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's in the sale.DateSold.Month.  My guess is its in your performCurrencyConversion method, but I can't be sure without a stack trace.

Comment: What are you going to be using the date for? The reason I ask is that you are setting the date back as the date sold. However, what happens if the date is from a previous year?

Comment: Did you try 
`DateSold = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, ds.Key, 1)`
 to resolve the error? 
 (But you should make sure you only get stuff for the last 12 months.)

Comment: What is the purpose of DateSold being of DateTime type ? You want to set this property based on a grouping, so I would expect that you get various dates (and possibly times if you make use of them at all) within your groupings. Unless it's only yearMonth that you want, in which case I would create a struct to hold this info to make the purpose clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest introducing a new type to represent `YearMonth` if that's what you need (see my question in comments).

BTW: If you are grouping by month only, then you can have problems in case when you get overlapping data, e.g. the data set contains data for `201101` and `201201` - both would be grouped together. When you do the grouping by yearMonth this should not be an issue.

The new type would be pretty basic (could be a struct):

```
public class YearMonthSold
{
    public int Year {get; set;}
    public int Month {get; set;}
}
```

MonthlySales would get this property:

```
public YearMonthSold DateSold { get; set; }
```

And the LINQ query would need updated to make use of it:

```
List<MonthlySales> monthlySales = (from sale in Sales
                        orderby sale.DateSold descending
                        group sale by new {Year = sale.DateSold.Year, Month = sale.DateSold.Month} into ds
                        select new MonthlySales
                        {
                            DateSold = new YearMonthSold {Year = ds.Key.Year, Month = ds.Key.Month},
                            (...)
                        })
                       .Take(12)
                       .ToList();
```

EDIT:
Or as suggested by SPFiredrake:

```
List<MonthlySales> monthlySales = (from sale in Sales
                        orderby sale.DateSold descending
                        group sale by new YearMonthSold {Year = sale.DateSold.Year, Month = sale.DateSold.Month} into ds
                        select new MonthlySales
                        {
                            DateSold = ds.Key,
                            (...)
                        })
                       .Take(12)
                       .ToList();
```

I don't know the code for the `Sale` object, but it doesn't seem that it should be affected by this change in any way.

Comment: I don't understand why you're implementing a new object and using an anonymous class at the same time. You might as well do `group sale by new YearMonthSold { Year = sale.DateSold.Year, Month = sale.DateSold.Month } ...` and assign it directly from the `select new...`. Otherwise, you're creating two objects when you only need one.

Comment: @SPFiredrake - you're right, I added the option above. I did the grouping by an anonymous type before I thought about introducing a new type, that's why it was left behind in the query. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend would be to set the key to the first of the month in question, that way you also have the year information present (which you will need since you want the last 12 months).

```
...
group sale by sale.DateSold.Date.AddDays(-(sale.DateSold.Day - 1)) into ds
orderby ds.Key descending
...
```

You also want to order by after the grouping instead of before, since grouping uses hash of keys instead of values, so you might not get the same ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you group by DateTime, so you will be able to set « DateSold » with « ds.Key ».
And if you want the Month of the DateTime store in the Key, you can just « ds.Key.Month ».

Comment: You could group by `new DateTime(DateSold.Year, DateSold.Month, 1)`.

Comment: Why to create a new DateTime while we already have the DateSold DateTime ?

Comment: In order _not_ to group by date, but by month. I.e. ignore the day part (and possible time) of the Datetime.

Comment: Creating a new DateTime is not that expensive, so that should be OK. However, grouping by `DateSold` is a bad idea to begin with, because it will create a new group for every DISTINCT DateTime (meaning even fractional second differences will cause a new group).